# ValueError at /user/register Cannot assign "('Civil Engineering (CE)',)": "User.department" must be a "Department" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I cannot insert data into a database.
I want to create a user with specific department name and the department table, with a foreign key to detect the user from a certain department.
Here is my model file:

```
class Department(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
admin_id = models.ForeignKey('Admin' , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
admin_post_id = models.ForeignKey('Admin_Post' , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return name
```

This is my custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
      address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      phone_number = models.IntegerField( blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
      department = models.ForeignKey('Department' , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      semester = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
      registation = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
      password = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
      password_con = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=True)
      USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
      REQUIRED_FIELD = ['email']
      objects = UserManager()
      def _str__(self):
         return registration;
```

Here is my view file:

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      first_name     = request.POST['first_name']
      last_name      = request.POST['last_name']
      address        = request.POST['address']
      phone_number   = request.POST['phone_number']
      department     = request.POST['department']
      semester       = request.POST['semester']
      registration    = request.POST['registration']
      email          = request.POST['email']
      password       = request.POST['password']
      password_con   = request.POST['password_con']
      user = Department()
      user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name ,last_name=last_name ,address=address ,phone_number=phone_number ,department=department ,semester=semester ,registration=registration ,email=email ,password=password)
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.info(request,'Email is Already taken')
    elif User.objects.filter(registration=registration):
        messages.info(request,'Registration Id is Already taken')
    elif password != password_con:
        messages.info(request,'Credentials not mathcing')
    else:

        # user.department = Department.objects.get()
        user.save()
        print('user created')
        return redirect('signin/')
else:
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

Comment: So user is a Department() then it gets reassigned to user create user then what are you saving with user.save() ?

Comment: The identation in the post does seem to be wrong - can you please correct this.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to make a database relation out from a name, you can't do that in Django.
You must first retrieve the `Department` instance that correponds to the `POST` data and the give it so that Django creates a foreign key relation.

Something like this

```
# retrieve object
department_instance = Department.objects.get(name=request.POST['department']) # here 'Civil Engineering (CE)'
# use the instance (actually only the ID of that instance will be stored in the table User, but that's a detail)
User.objects.create_user(department=department_instance.id, etc...) #you can omit '.id'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still remain the same

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
department     =    request.POST['department']
```

should be something like:

```
department     =    Department.objects.get(id=request.POST['department'])
```

Comment: maybe what you nedd is the Django ModelForm, which takes care of validating a HTML form according to the model specification. Django's Forms can event generate themselves in HTML.
If you are creating a REST-like backend, take a look at DjangoRestFramework, especially its ModelSerializers